# Calling methods by number

Tags: c#

Let's say I've got 6 methods: `Method1()`, `Method2()`, `Method3()`, `Method4()`, `Method5()` and `Method6()`. I also have another method, `SuperMethod(int nr)`, that will call one of the other methods. If the input to `SuperMethod` is 1, `Method1()` will be called and so on.

Can this be done in an elegant way without having a switch statement or stacking if-else statements?

*I should add that this is not important production code I'm writing, so performance is not an issue.*

Comment: You could probaby do something fancy with reflection, but I'd suggest something a little more readable, perhaps a `Dictionary<int,Action>` or similar.

Comment: Why not inject the method to be called within `SuperMethod` rather than passing a magic number?

Comment: Id suggest an array of delegates/actions, a dictionary provides more flexibility but an array might be outright faster

Comment: Sounds like a very bad design.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This seems like something which might be better solved with a redesign of the classes involved, although there isn't enough information to know that for sure.

Comment: This could be an implantation of a command pattern where an enum or some other discriminator is used to invoke a command.  Which is generally handled by a switch unless the command can be implemented polymorphicly.

Answer (score 6):

you can use delegates and it is also interesting for solving real world problems with short programs:

```
    public void CollatzTest(int n)
    {
        var f = new Func<int, int>[] { i => i / 2, i => i * 3 + 1 };

        while (n != 1)
            n = f[n % 2](n);
    }
```

that also works with actions, and direct method references

```
    private void DelegateActionStartTest()
    {
        Action[] Actions = new Action[] { UselesstTest, IntervalTest, Euler13 };

        int nFunction = 2;

        Actions[nFunction]();
    }
```

Comment: Personally, I would much prefer to encounter this or something similar using Action<> in a code base than reflection.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say I've got 6 methods: Method1(), Method2()...

Then you have horrible method names.  I would name the methods appropriately (based on what they *do* and/or *return*) then create a mapping of integers to methods using a `Dictionary<int,Func<???>>`.

`SuperMethod` (another horrible method name) would then look up the method in the dictionary and execute it.

Comment: "Let's say" means that the methods names are not the real ones, but used as an example...

Answer (score 1):

```
void Method1() { Console.WriteLine("M1"); }

void Method2() { Console.WriteLine("M2"); }

void SuperMethod(int nr)
{
    var mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("Method" + nr, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
    mi.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a static class with a static list or array.  Constant lookup time and access and since an integer is you key and its contiguous a dictionary provides little advantage.

```
static class Super
{
    static void M1()
    {
    }
    static void M2()
    {
    }
    static List<Action> Actions = new List<Action>(); 
    static Super()
    {
        Actions.Add(M1);
        Actions.Add(M2); 
    }
    static void CallSupper(int nr)
    {
        try
        {
            Actions[nr - 1](); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance I might have a design re-think (as others have commented).

If you really want to use reflection and assuming we are within a class instance, you could do it like this

```
void SuperMethod(int nr)
{   
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Method" + nr);
    methodInfo.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Comment: I dont think the overhead is worth it, but nice solution anyways.

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily the right approach (I was merely trying to show a solution to the exact problem in question), but it is difficult to say without more on what is trying to be achieved. I have added a waiver to this effect.